# Eclipse IDE v2020-12 (4.18.0) insists one of my javascript files is an HTML file and flags every use of && as invalid character

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

In a Java dynamic web project in Eclipse v2020-12, in a folder called WebContent, I have several JavaScript files with file extension .js
Most work fine in the editor, but one is consistently flagged with the warning:

```
Invalid character used in text string (//filename.js  [...] line 248 HTML Problem
```

The particular line that is flagged in the file (line 248) contains an if expression with &&
The double ampersand is flagged with a warning because this is an invalid sequence of characters in an HTML file.

Right clicking on the file in the Package Explorer and selecting "Properties", the Resource tab shows that eclipse thinks it is an HTML file, not a JavaScript file -- Type: File (HTML)
All the other JavaScript files in the same directory show Properties->Resource->Type: File (JavaScript Source File).

So, I know why it is flagging this one file for a double ampersand as invalid but I don't know why it insists this particular JavaScript file is an HTML file.  I cannot find a way to change this Type.

My questions:

1. Why does eclipse decide this is an HTML file, not a JavaScript file?
2. How can I reset the properties associated with this file in eclipse?
3. How to prevent eclipse from making this incorrect file association again?

Comment: Check your Content Types preference page. Did you do something that added filename.js to the HTML content type?

Comment: Right-click a `.js` file, choose _Open With > Other..._, in the _Select Editor_ dialog choose the _Generic Text Editor_, tick _Use it for all '*.js' files and click _OK_.

Comment: Thank you nitind and howlger for the prompt and helpful responses!
I checked Window->Preferences->General->Content Types

Sure enough, Content Type HTML listed all the usual extensions, plus the full filename and extension of that one troublesome JavaScript file!

I don't know how I managed to associate that one file with content type HTML, but that was definitely the problem.  I removed that content type association and rebuilt the project and the warning has gone away.

Thank you for your help!  You saved me so much time!